# How do I get button to fire click, if first hidden by blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hidden

Hi I have an editable area (textinput or contenteditable) and a button.
I would like the button to hide when the area looses focus - 
but clicking on the button will loose focus, hide the button,

BUT THE BUTTON DOES NOT GET ANY CLICK EVENT ANYMORE.... ;-(

1. first click in the blue text area,
2. then click the button
3. the button should fire click and alert - but it doesn't !!

http://jsfiddle.net/3295f/

```
    <div contenteditable="true" 
    style="width:300px;height:300px;border:3px solid blue;z-index:100;position:relative;" 
    onblur="$('button').hide()" > 
    </div>

    <button onclick="alert(1)">pushme</button>
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

I was never expecting this to be a problem in the first place...

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: The button hides when the area loses focus, So whats the problem?

Comment: Redo it - click on the button to loose focus - then you will NOT get the click event fired - _just_ a blur() hiding the button...

Comment: I just noticed that the hide() is not even crucial ... http://jsfiddle.net/5E57b/ ... I totally don't understand....!!!

Comment: @sebhaase alert() is modal. In debugging purpose, use console.log() instead  http://jsfiddle.net/5E57b/1/

Comment: @Wolff - alert() is much easier to see and it did not change the behavior -- I don't think that justifies a downvote ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this workaround instead:

```
<button onmousedown="alert(1)">pushme</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3295f/2/

Comment: It looks like you also took out the blur !?  ref. http://jsfiddle.net/3295f/4/ for a cleaned up version

Comment: @sebhaase No i didn't, i use instead onfocusout which bubbles. I'm just anticipating your next question when your DIV will have some content

Comment: could you explain in words, what this clearQueue thing should be doing !?

Comment: The DOC explains it all. Indeed in your specific case, it should be useless here but, as a good practice, i clear the queue (it could be dequeue instead)

Comment: I meant you took out the onblur which should do the hide button !

Comment: @sebhaase so then use mousedown as here: http://jsfiddle.net/3295f/2/   Or better: http://jsfiddle.net/3295f/5/

Comment: Sorry - I missed the second jsfiddle -- that is good !!
 jsfiddle.net/3295f/5  is not good because it even fires the alert when clicking next to the button

- Why is mousedown "better" (i.e. different) than click ?  Then I also need touchstart and alike for supporting touch devices....